# How to run Canopy IDE in terminal?

Tags: python, error-handling, canopy

When I trying to run Canopy I am getting the following error:

```
/home/jaffels/canopy/bin/python: 1: /home/jaffels/canopy/bin/python: ELF: not found
/home/jaffels/canopy/bin/python: 9: /home/jaffels/canopy/bin/python: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
```

It also creates a file with the following name: �@@�C@8@ (invalid encoding)

Can anybody please help with the error below in the terminal

Answer (score 2):

Found the error. I was trying to install the 64bit version on a 32bit system

Comment: What is your system?

Comment: It was Ubuntu, can't remember which version of Ubuntu as it was 4 years ago when I had the issue

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use GUI you can see here useful [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tjY1cODOq9Q). For example, in ubuntu:
[image]

In the case when you want to use canopy without GUI, you need to activate your virtual environment using source: `~/my_venv/bin/activate`. More about you can find here: http://docs.enthought.com/canopy/quick-start/canopy_terminal.html.